# Update a Facebook event using the graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to update an existing Facebook event, created by my application. I'm using the PHP SDK to create the event, here is the code for creating the event:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$page_id = $_SESSION['FAN_PAGE_ID'];

// Now, getting the PAGE Access token, using the user access token

$page_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id?fields=access_token&" . $access_token;
$response = file_get_contents($page_token_url);

// Parse the return value and get the Page access token
$resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);

$page_access_token = $resp_obj['access_token'];

$event_param = array(
    "access_token" =>$page_access_token,
    "name" => $postEventName,
    "start_time" => $postEventDate,
    "page_id" => $postFanPageID,
    "description" => $eventDescription,
    "location" => $location
);

try
{
   $fb_event_id = $facebook->api("/$postFanPageID/events", "POST", $event_param);
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is successfully creating an event. But I haven't found any documentation about updating an event.

I've tried using the same call but providing my existing `eventID`:

```
$facebook->api("/$postFanPageID/events/$facebookEventID", "POST", $event_param);
```

that just created a new event.

I've tried using this (similar to the code of deleting an event):

```
$facebook->api($facebookEventID, 'UPDATE', $event_param);
```

But this returned: `Unsupported method` by Facebook.

How can I update an event ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit an event you have to post against the event id only – so *not* `/$postFanPageID/events/$facebookEventID`, but just `/$facebookEventID` instead.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events